# Setting a TextView textColor changes the whole ListView items color

Tags: android, listview

I'm setting an ArrayAdapter like this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_product_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtProductName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_name);
    TextView txtProductRemaining = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_remaining);
    TextView txtProductPrice = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_sale_price);

    String productName = getItem(position).productName;
    String productRemaining = Number.floatToStringAsNumber(getItem(position).productRemaining);
    String productPrice = Number.floatToStringAsPrice(getItem(position).productSellPrice, true);

    txtProductName.setText(productName);
    txtProductRemaining.setText(productRemaining);
    txtProductPrice.setText(productPrice);

    /**
     * Coloring
     */
    if (getItem(position).productRemaining <= 0){
        txtProductRemaining.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff7f7f"));
    }

    return view;

}
```

Whenever the evaluation on the last line returns true, it paints every single txtProductRemaining. I need to paint only the evaluated item. Why does it paint the whole set of elements?

Comment: u sure of your if condition?

Comment: Yes. as @A.A. menctioned, whenever it changes, the whole adapter will set if permanently. So i have to add an 'else' condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListView` reuses views so once one item is colored, other views will be colored as well on load. Here is what you need to do to avoid that:

```
if (getItem(position).productRemaining <= 0){
    txtProductRemaining.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff7f7f"));
}
else {
     txtProductRemaining.setTextColor(Color.BLACK));. // Or whatever default color you prefer
}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)

Comment: As soon as the min time passes by